# How to Drag UIBezierPath in UiView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibezierpath

I successfully create the `UIBezierPath` now I want to drag that path in UIView on drag event(`UIPanGestureRecognizer`) and get the current location's  points contended by that path.

Is it possible that we can only drag UIBezierPath from one place to another? in UIView.

Answer (score 6):

If you allow me to toot my own horn, I blogged about this topic a while ago in a post titled [CGPath Hit Testing](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/). The demo app that I talk about in the article has the capability you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for replay. i download that tutorial its very confusing to me because i am new in iOS development. if u give me that code which can drag the path than it will very help full to me.

Comment: I don't think it would help you much if I posted the code here out of context. Look at the view controller's code to see how I react to the pan gesture recognizer and then check how the view redraws itself (with new model data) whenever a successful drag is in progress.

Comment: is it possible that we can only drag UIBezierPath from one pace to another? in UIVIEW

Comment: @SmartWork Spend some more time reading that article.  It is very well written, and answers your question precisely.  If you started reading it the second Ole posted his answer, you didn't have anywhere near enough time to go through that and gain a good understanding.  You say you are new to iOS development.  Fair enough.  However, you need to invest a HUGE amount of time into learning... and since that article addresses a specific concern of yours, I think it's a great place to start learning how to work through technical documents.

Comment: @JodyHagins thanks for advice, i will keep in mind your advice.thanks again.